# Model construction using ELMo embeddings and Bi-LSTM issue for sentence level token classification problem

Tags: tensorflow, nlp, lstm, tensorflow2.0, word-embedding

**I'm working on this project: [Jargon Detection](https://www.kaggle.com/competitions/jargon-detection/overview)**

Data was cleaned and padded sequences were formed.

- Language: Python (3.9.x)
- Framework: tensorflow (2.12.x) [tensorflow-deps           2.9.0                         0    apple
  tensorflow-estimator      2.12.0                   pypi_0    pypi
  tensorflow-hub            0.13.0                   pypi_0    pypi
  tensorflow-macos          2.12.0                   pypi_0    pypi
  tensorflow-metal          0.8.0                    pypi_0    pypi]

**Model code:**

```
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Input, LSTM, Embedding, Dense, TimeDistributed, Dropout, Bidirectional, Lambda, Layer, Concatenate
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential, Model
import tensorflow_hub as hub

elmo_model = hub.load("https://tfhub.dev/google/elmo/3").signatures["default"]
class ElmoEmbeddings(Layer):
    def __init__(self, elmo_model, max_len, **kwargs):
        super(ElmoEmbeddings, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.elmo_model = elmo_model
        self.max_len = max_len
    
    def call(self, inputs):
        embeddings_list = []
        # Iterate over input sequences and compute embeddings
        for sequence in inputs:
            input_tensor = tf.constant(sequence)
            embeddings = elmo_model(input_tensor)['elmo']
            print(f"embeddings shape: {embeddings.shape}")
            # Extract the tensor from the dictionary and append to the list
            embeddings_list.append(embeddings)
    
        # Stack the embeddings
        stacked_embeddings = tf.stack(embeddings_list)
    
        # Squeeze the extra dimension
        stacked_embeddings = tf.squeeze(stacked_embeddings, axis=2)
        return stacked_embeddings
    
    def compute_output_shape(self, input_shape):
        return (input_shape[0], self.max_len, 1024)
# Define inputs
input_layer = Input(shape=(max_len,), dtype=tf.string, name='input_layer')
elmo_embeddings = ElmoEmbeddings(elmo_model, max_len, name='elmo_embeddings')(input_layer)
lstm_output = Bidirectional(LSTM(units=512, return_sequences=True, recurrent_dropout=0.2, dropout=0.2, name='lstm'))(elmo_embeddings)
output = TimeDistributed(Dense(n_tags, activation='softmax', name='dense'))(lstm_output)

# Define model
tech_jargon_model = Model(inputs=input_layer, outputs=output)
tech_jargon_model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])

# Train model
history = tech_jargon_model.fit(
    tf.constant(X_tr), y_tr,
    validation_data=(tf.constant(X_val), y_val),
    batch_size=batch_size,
    epochs=3,
    verbose=1
)
```

**Input:**

```
X_tr : 18916
X_tr[0] : 25
X_tr: <class 'list'>

y_tr : 18916
y_tr[0] : 25
y_tr: <class 'numpy.ndarray'>
```

**Error:**

```
TypeError: Exception encountered when calling layer "elmo_embeddings" (type ElmoEmbeddings).

in user code:

    File "/var/folders/yq/qh4ny6ms3kz0yqqj4q2gqkn00000gn/T/ipykernel_4686/880792685.py", line 11, in call  *
        input_tensor = tf.constant(sequence)

    TypeError: Expected any non-tensor type, but got a tensor instead.


Call arguments received by layer "elmo_embeddings" (type ElmoEmbeddings):
  • inputs=tf.Tensor(shape=(None, 25), dtype=string)
```

I tried many different ways to pass the input to elmo_model but every time some error pops up.

I used the same above method in a **sample** as shown below and got the expected output but was unable to replicate the same when used in a Model context.

**Sample and code:**

tokens_input = [["the", "cat", "is", "on", "the", "mat"],
["dogs", "are", "in", "the", "fog", ""]]

```
tokens_input = tf.constant(tokens_input)
print(f"tokens_input: {type(tokens_input)}")
# Initialize an empty list to store embeddings
embeddings_list = []

# Iterate over input sequences and compute embeddings
for sequence in tokens_input:
    input_tensor = tf.constant(sequence)
    embeddings = elmo_model(input_tensor)['elmo']
    print(f"embeddings shape: {embeddings.shape}")
    # Extract the tensor from the dictionary and append to the list
    embeddings_list.append(embeddings)
    
# Stack the embeddings
stacked_embeddings = tf.stack(embeddings_list)

# Squeeze the extra dimension
stacked_embeddings = tf.squeeze(stacked_embeddings, axis=2)

# Print the shape of the stacked embeddings
print(f"Stacked embeddings shape: {stacked_embeddings.shape}")
print(f"Stacked embeddings type: {type(stacked_embeddings)}")
**Output:**
tokens_input: <class 'tensorflow.python.framework.ops.EagerTensor'>
embeddings shape: (6, 1, 1024)
embeddings shape: (6, 1, 1024)
Stacked embeddings shape: (2, 6, 1024)
Stacked embeddings type: <class 'tensorflow.python.framework.ops.EagerTensor'>
```

Given the model definition and problem statement, how can this issue be resolved?